# How to kill old instance of phantomjs by monit

Tags: phantomjs, monit

I have a program that using `phantomjs`.
There should be only a instance for the program and there is no program using `Phantomjs`.

But sometimes `Phantomjs` are launched several instances sametime. Probably my program have a bug. For quick fix I want to kill old instance if there are `Phantomjs` instance more than one by monit.

I can find the instances of Phantomjs by using `matching` function in `monit`. But I couldn't find out how to compare two instance status and kill old one.

I'd be very grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use a timestamp on each instance then use:

```
.quit()
```

On the oldest instance?

This method kills the instance and all resources.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want to know how to compare the time stamps of multiple instance in monit, not the way how to kill the instance. Or am I misunderstanding your answer?